# How to convert a query to linq

Tags: sql

I have two data tables which are identical i.e. both have a column called `EventId` as their primary keys.

The first data table (`FilteredEvents`) contains all events i.e. ones that I don't need as well as ones that I need.

The second data table (`EventToBeCreated`) contains the events that need to be created.

Here is an example:

`FilteredEvents` contains IDs:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5

`EventToBeCreated` contains IDs:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4

In this example, the correct result would be `5`, as it is in `FilteredEvents`, but not in `EventToBeCreated`.

This SQL query does what I need, but I need the LINQ equivalent:

```
SELECT Event_Filtered.EventID 
FROM Event_Filtered 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Event_ToBeCreated 
  ON Event_Filtered.EventID = Event_ToBeCreated.EventID
WHERE (Event_ToBeCreated.EventID IS NULL)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Subject says "convert query to linq", but the linq-to-sql is used. Contradictionary.

Comment: *but I need the LINQ equivalent* So use your LINQ-to-SQL model classes.

Comment: I removed the [linq-to-sql] tag because now it appears you're working with data tables, a detail you didn't deem necessary to mention upfront.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide entity details and other required informations, it should be something like that;

```
var query = from ef in yourContext.Event_Filtered
            join et in yourContext.Event_ToBeCreated on ef.EventID equals et.EventID into ps
            from ps in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where et.EventID == null
            select ef.EventID
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am using DataTable i.e

var Event_Filtered = new DataTable();
Event_Filtered.Columns.Add("EventId", typeof(int));

var Event_ToBeCreated = new DataTable();
Event_ToBeCreated.Columns.Add("EventId", typeof(int));

Comment: As usual, a 1:1 translation from SQL `JOIN` to LINQ `join`. But the class model *probably* contains navigation properties. That's why it's a fruitless effort to translate SQL to LINQ without having details about the C# classes.

Comment: There are no classes. There are two DataTables and I want the result of the LEFT OUTER JOIN to populate a third DataTable.